# Longest subsequence with alternating increasing and decreasing values

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

Given an array , we need to find the length of longest sub-sequence with alternating increasing and decreasing values.

For example , if the array is , 
`7 4 8 9 3 5 2 1` then the `L = 6` for `7,4,8,3,5,2` or `7,4,9,3,5,1` , etc.

It could also be the case that first we have small then big element.

What could be the most efficient solution for this ? I had a DP solution in mind. And if we were to do it using brute force how would we do it (O(n^3) ?) ?

And it's not a homework problem.

Comment: Nope. I don't do SPOJ. More like a variant of the LIS.

Comment: Have you google longest bitonic subsequence ? Lots of answers ...

Comment: @Kwariz Bitonic sequence is one which is first increasing and then decreasing. Here it is ALTERNATING.

Comment: @sTEAK look at the algorithms, it is trivial to change an increasing first algorithm to a decreasing first algorithm. Worst case you have to run it twice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You indeed can use dynamic programming approach here. For sake of simplicity , assume we need to find only the maximal length of such sequence **seq** (it will be easy to tweak solution to find the sequence itself).

For each index we will store 2 values:

- maximal length of alternating sequence ending at that element where last step was increasing (say, **incr**[i])
- maximal length of alternating sequence ending at that element where last step was decreasing (say, **decr**[i])

also by definition we assume `incr[0] = decr[0] = 1`

then each incr[i] can be found recursively:

```
incr[i] = max(decr[j])+1, where j < i and seq[j] < seq[i]
decr[i] = max(incr[j])+1, where j < i and seq[j] > seq[i]
```

Required length of the sequence will be the maximum value in both arrays, complexity of this approach is O(N*N) and it requires 2N of extra memory (where N is the length of initial sequence)

simple example in c:

```
int seq[N]; // initial sequence
int incr[N], decr[N];

... // Init sequences, fill incr and decr with 1's as initial values

for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j){
         if (seq[j] < seq[i]) 
         {
             // handle "increasing" step - need to check previous "decreasing" value
             if (decr[j]+1 > incr[i])  incr[i] = decr[j] + 1;
         }
         if (seq[j] > seq[i]) 
         {
             if (incr[j]+1 > decr[i])  decr[i] = incr[j] + 1;
         }
    }
}

... // Now all arrays are filled, iterate over them and find maximum value
```

How algorithm will work:

**step 0** (initial values):

```
seq  = 7   4 8 9 3 5 2 1
incr = 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1
decr = 1   1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

**step 1** take value at index 1 ('4') and check previous values. 7 > 4 so we make "decreasing step from index 0 to index 1, new sequence values:

```
incr = 1 1   1 1 1 1 1 1
decr = 1 2   1 1 1 1 1 1
```

**step 2.** take value 8 and iterate over previous value:

7 < 8, make increasing step: incr[2] = MAX(incr[2], decr[0]+1):

```
incr = 1 1 2   1 1 1 1 1
decr = 1 2 1   1 1 1 1 1
```

4 < 8, make increasing step: incr[2] = MAX(incr[2], decr[1]+1):

```
incr = 1 1 3   1 1 1 1 1
decr = 1 2 1   1 1 1 1 1
```

etc...

Comment: Could you give a dry run of your algorithm please? For sake of more clarity. Thanks.

Comment: @sTEAK. sorry, you mean add some pseudocode or anything else? (my English lets me down here :( )

Comment: yes pseudo-code and an example of it. that is applying your algorithm on an example

Comment: in step 2 , why are you checking for 4<8 and then again doing incr[2] = ... , why not decr[2] = ... ?

Comment: @sTEAK. as 4 < 8 we can only make "increasing" step from 4 to 8 - so we need to check the length of sequence that ended with 4 and had decreasing last step (that is, decr[1]) to make sequence alternate. As 8 is bigger than all previous items we cannot make "decreasing" step to it so decr[2] remains 1